# Como crear datatable con otra tabla?

Tags: javascript, web, table, data

Estoy intentando crear una tabla con datos que al hacer click en el nombre del dato me renderize una nueva tabla al lado o abajo con los nuevos datos. Actualmente estoy usando datatable con javascript pero no encontré nada parecido. Alguno tiene idea de si esto es posible?

Adjunto imagen de que es lo que quiero lograr:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una tabla oculta que se muestre y cargue con los datos solicitados... pero debes agregar el codigo de lo que tienes y que has intentado

Comment: Aún no logré nada. Simplemente tablas simples con datatables. No se por donde empezar por eso pregunté si hay alguna librería o alguna otra forma de hacerlo

Comment: El tema de este tipo de preguntas, es que se basa en opiniones, puede venir X persona a decirte X cosa, pero viene otra y te dice otro, y ambas funcionan. La idea del sitio no es esa, y solo podría hacer que cierren tu pregunta. Lo que debes hacer en este caso, es buscar como mostrar una tabla nueva al presionar un boton, y cargarle los datos con AJAX o JQUERY y mostrarla luego de cargados los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor para preguntar en StackOverflow es que muestres algo de código, para ver que has intentado, y sobre todo entender qué es lo que necesitas. De todas formas este es un ejemplo básico, pero la estructura realmente depende de donde tengas la información que quieres mostrar.

En resumen es más o menos así:

- Dibujas en HTML la tabla principal. Debe haber un botón/link/celda, donde el usuario hará clic para mostrar la tabla de datos de esa fila.
- Los datos de esa fila debes tenerlos previamente en un objeto JavaScript u obtenerlos vía AJAX mediante un servicio web (en el ejemplo: las filas son "*empresas*" y los datos son los "*contactos*" de la empresa).
- Una vez que tengas los datos: creas la tabla (`table`, las filas (`tr`) y celdas (`td`) mostrando los datos, y luego agregas la tabla a la pantalla (dentro del `div` *output*).

No agregué ninguna librería (Vue, React, jQuery...) porque lo pides parece simple.

```js
//El HTML muestra los datos maestros (en el ejemplo es una lista de empresas)
//La variable "datos" tiene los contactos de cada empresa:
const datos = {
  1: [{ nombre: 'Juan', email: 'juan@ejemplo.com' },
    { nombre: 'Maria', email: 'maria@ejemplo.com' }],
  2: [{ nombre: 'Carlos', email: 'carlos@ejemplo.com' },
    { nombre: 'Jhonny', email: 'jhonny@ejemplo.com' },
    { nombre: 'Ángela', email: 'angela@ejemplo.com' }],
  3: [{ nombre: 'Pedro', email: 'pedro@ejemplo.com' }]
}

//Con esto "escuchamos" los clics de cada botón "btnMostrar":
const botones = document.querySelectorAll('.btnMostrar');
botones.forEach((item) => {
  const id = item.dataset['id'];
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    mostrarDatos(id)
  });
});

//Esto muestra los datos (contactos) de una empresa 
//al hacer clic en el botón correspondiente
const mostrarDatos = function(id) {

  //Encabezado
  let nombre = document.createElement('th');
  nombre.textContent = 'Nombre';
  let email = document.createElement('th');
  email.textContent = 'Email';

  let fila = document.createElement('tr');
  fila.appendChild(nombre);
  fila.appendChild(email);

  const tablaNueva = document.createElement('table');
  tablaNueva.appendChild(fila);

  //Detalles
  const contactos = datos[id];
  contactos.forEach((item) => {

    nombre = document.createElement('td');
    nombre.textContent = item.nombre;

    email = document.createElement('td');
    email.textContent = item.email;

    fila = document.createElement('tr');
    fila.appendChild(nombre);
    fila.appendChild(email);

    tablaNueva.appendChild(fila);

  });


  //Borra la tabla vieja y dibuja la nueva
  const output = document.querySelector('#output');
  output.innerHTML = '';
  output.appendChild(tablaNueva);

}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 4px
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Datos</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Electrical Services Inc </td>
      <td><button class="btnMostrar" data-id="1">Contactos</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Company C.A. </td>
      <td><button class="btnMostrar" data-id="2">Contactos</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Master Pizzas </td>
      <td><button class="btnMostrar" data-id="3">Contactos</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Contactos: </h2>
<div id="output">

</div>
```